# Internet connection with static IP

Tags: server, networking

I have installed ubuntu server 11.04 edition (with LAMP, mail server, and SSH server) and I try to connect to the internet. When I plug the cable from my ISP with the configuration provided below to a router and then back to my server the connection works fine, but when I try to put the cable directly to my server without the router, with the same information configuration the internet connection doesn't work any more.

```
resolv.conf
nameserver 81.180.166.1

eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:12:79:a5:0b:39
inet addr:81.180.166.151 Bcast:81.180.167.255 Mask:255.255.254.0
inet6 addr: fe80::212:79ff:fea5:b39/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:5697 errors:0 dropped:1854 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets 34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:467192 TX bytes:2594
interrupt:25
```

In /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
ip:81.180.166.151 
subnetmask:255.255.254.0 
gateway:81.180.166.1 
dns: 193.230.240.16 
mac:00 0E A6 41 C6 38.
```

Comment: Could you also paste the output of 'ip route show'?

Comment: 81.180.166.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 81.180.166.151 default via 81.180.166.1 dev eth0 metric 100                                        81.180.166.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 81.180.166.151 default via 81.180.166.1 dev eth0 metric 100

Comment: How do you connect with your static connection to the internet? Do you have a router in the middle, modem, anything? I dont belive your ISP installed a cable straight to your home to share their private network with you ;)

Tell me more about your network, where is what connected, how many NICs you have output your `ifconfig -a` with the dynamic net and the static one connected.

Comment: Can you write down what your ISP said it would be your IP address, gateway IP and DNS servers? Do you have only 1 NIC? (So 1 card, 2 different connections?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line stating the IP address for the DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` should read

```
nameserver 193.230.240.16
```

rather than being the IP address of the gateway (81.180.166.1), if that is what the ISP says the DNS server should be.